# Storing complex object graphs in Parcelable?

Tags: android, parcelable

Existing Parcelable examples are rather trivial. If you have a complex object graph the following questions arise quickly questioning the feasibility:

1. Is there any way to prevent an object being written multiple time into a parcel?
2. Are there any best practices to limit the depth of the object graph while writing?

To give an example for the first question, object A references B, which in turn references A. This cycle leads to writes A, B, A, B, A, ... until we get an StackOverflowError because there does not seem to be a way to just reference an object that was previously written.

For the second question let's we have a long graph A->B->C->D->E, and we want to serialize A with an additional depth of 2, which would be just A->B->C. We did this by writing a custom writeToParcelDeep method, which is of course not as convenient as the standard writeToParcel.

Answer (score 0):

Java serialization will preserve reference and write a object just once. Also current devices are much more powerful than the ones from the past and I'm not so sure that performance gain is justifying writing Parcelable biolerplate code especially complicated one as in your example.

I'll keep using serializable and you can read more about my findings on this topic [here](https://medium.com/nemanja-kovacevic/yet-another-post-on-serializable-vs-parcelable-1e829e98472).